# Kernel Problems randomly restarting MacMini Late 2012

Tags: macos, mac-mini, kernel-panic

I have a MacMini (late 2012) running the latest Yosemite version 10.10.4 and I get ocasional random restarts. Sometimes they occur right after I login from one of these restarts, other times it is stable for quite a while (can be hours or days) and then restarts again.

I have unplugged all external peripherals (Firewire HDD and Thunderbolt HDD) but I am still using dual-monitors: one direct HDMI and the other using mini display to HDMI adaptor.

The only modifications I made was to replace the original internal HDD which was very slow (5,400 rpm) to a Crucial SSD 512GB and I replaced the RAM to by Crucial 2x8GB DDR3 - 1600 as well which I believe they are both highly recommended and compatible with Mac machines. The SSD model is Crucial_CT512MX100SSD1. Could it be something related to the hardware replacement?

The two last kernel errors are here: http://d.pr/n/128a5/b5RQaBL8 and http://d.pr/n/1hF51/3BiwFQ6N

I am up to reinstall the whole OSX from scratch if I need to. This was the only way I found to solve a Divx codec issue in the past in a different machine after exhausting all possible

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Many thanks to all.

Comment: I have the same problem and a similar configuration: Mac Mini Late 2012 Fusion Drive.
Mac OS 10.10.4.
Dual Monitors plugged using both hdmi and Mini-Display (via dvi adapter).
I changed the Ram to 2x8GB Samsung one year ago. I didn't have any problem with this configuration for the last 6 months.
Did you find a solution? Or re-installed mac OS X from scratch?

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I didn't find a solution yet but two things we have in common that may be the reason behind these problems is the RAM change and dual monitors plugged in. However, I have a very strong intuition that the problem may be exactly because of the dual-monitors... sometimes (very rarely) the screens go black and I can never turn them on. I need to force a restart by pressing the off button and then it is fine. I am not using an official Apple Mini-Display adapter which can be a problem as well... just guessing here.

Comment: I have same problem and I am almost sure it's an OSX bug, since it started about a month ago, while I didn't change any hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue appeared with 10.10.3, I am 98% certain it is a bug in OS X Yosemite, introduced with the 10.10.3 update and related to Intel HD 4000 GPUs. Welcome [aboard](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724). The kernel panics are totally erratic, some users have also graphics glitches. The only common feature is having a Intel HD 4000 GPU.

On MacBook Pros with dual GPU you can avoid the problem by **disabling Automatic Graphics Switching** (System Preferences > Energy Saver).

Please contribute to the [thread in the apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724) and file a bug report (with link to the thread).

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem. It done for forcefully shut down any file. To solve the problem press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> from your keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: What's the difference between cmd-alt-p-n-r and the common pram reset cmd-alt-p-r? Just some more finger acrobatics?